# RabbitMQ Java client: Connection refused

Tags: java, docker, rabbitmq, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I have a `rabbitmq:management` docker image running inside WSL2

> Note that I do **not have Docker Desktop installed**! I am running docker *inside* WSL2, **without** Docker Desktop

I can access `localhost:15672`, `127.0.0.1:15672` and `[::1]:15672` to get to the management interface without any issues, so the principal connectivity from my browser to the docker service in WSL2 is working.

However, when trying to connect with the RabbitMQ Java client library, I always get `connection refused` errors:

```java
try {
    var port = Env.get(EnvVars.EVENTING_PORT, "5672");
    var host = Env.get(EnvVars.EVENTING_HOST, "localhost");

    var factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost(host);
    factory.setPort(Integer.parseInt(port));

    LOG.info("Connecting on [{}:{}]", host, port);
    connection = factory.newConnection();
} catch (Exception exc) {
    LOG.error("Could not connect", exc);
}
```

The exception is from `java.net` so it must be some kind of networking error.

However: I also have redis in the same WSL2 docker running and I can connect to that via `localhost:6937` without any problems.

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                                                                                                        NAMES
47a58db1aa67   rabbitmq:management   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   18 minutes ago   Up 18 minutes   4369/tcp, 5671-5672/tcp, 15691-15692/tcp, 25672/tcp, 0.0.0.0:15671-15672->15671-15672/tcp, :::15671-15672->15671-15672/tcp   1264-services_rmq_1
8a792b0d0121   redis:4               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   18 minutes ago   Up 18 minutes   0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp, :::6379->6379/tcp                                                                                    1264-services_redis_1
```

How can I troubleshoot this to get the connection to rabbitmq from the java client library working as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rabbitmq-management is NOT listening on 5672 on localhost on VM, but only in container. For solve the issue run the rabbitmq container with option `-p 5671-5672:5671-5672`